# Cloud Code Error in Saving user

Tags: parse-platform

I have a function in my cloud code, which works, but I'm not sure how to fix a problem related to it.

Original Problem:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("assignTokenToUser", function(request, response) {
    console.log("Inside assignTokenToUser");
    var token = Math.random().toString(30).substring(7);
    query = new Parse.Query("User"),
    email = request.params.email;

    query.equalTo("username", email);


   query.find({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function(results) {
      query.first({
        success: function(user) {
          // Successfully retrieved the object.
          user.set("emailToken", token);
          user.save();
          console.log("success...");
          response.success(token);
        },
        error: function(error) {
          console.log("error 1...");
          response.error(error);
        }
      });
   }, function(error) {
     console.log("error 2...");
     response.error(error);
   });
});
```

This seemed to be a common problem after scanning the internet, and my analysis is that the useMasterKey needs to be passed each time we use the query object. Correspondingly, my log file shows that when trying to save the user, it gives a Code 206 error.

Log file output:

```
Inside assignTokenToUser
success...
^[[32minfo^[[39m: Ran cloud function assignTokenToUser for user undefined with:
  Input: {"email":"maryam.zafar@emumba.com"}
  Result: "p66qm34jd80p0j6ne03fe1q7f" functionName=assignTokenToUser, email=maryam.zafar@emumba.com, user=undefined
going to send an email... with result: p66qm34jd80p0j6ne03fe1q7f
fullLink: https://beatthegym.com/emailVerified?username=maryam.zafar@emumba.com&token=p66qm34jd80p0j6ne03fe1q7f
^[[31merror^[[39m: Error generating response. ParseError { code: 206, message: 'Cannot modify user 4m0VZFsKVt.' } code=206, message=Cannot modify user 4m0VZFsKVt.
[object Object]
```

So I went on to change my code to the following:

Code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("assignTokenToUser", function(request, response) {
     console.log("Inside assignTokenToUser");
    var token = Math.random().toString(30).substring(7);
    query = new Parse.Query("User"),
    email = request.params.email;

    query.equalTo("username", email);


    query.find({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function(results) {
      console.log("inside query.find...");
      query.first(null, { useMasterKey: true }).then(function(user) {
          console.log("inside query.first...");
          // Successfully retrieved the object.
          user.set("emailToken", token);
          user.save(null, { useMasterKey: true }).then(function() {
             console.log("inside user.save...");
             response.success();
          }, function(error) {
                response.error(error);
          });
          response.success(token);
        },
        function(error) {
          console.log("error 1...");
          response.error(error);
        });
   }, function(error) {
     console.log("error 2...");
     response.error(error);
   });
 });
```

Log file:

```
Inside assignTokenToUser
inside query.find...
inside query.first...
^[[32minfo^[[39m: Ran cloud function assignTokenToUser for user undefined with:
  Input: {"email":"maryam.zafar@emumba.com"}
  Result: "tqc8m9lo2tcsrqn69c3q0e1q7f" functionName=assignTokenToUser, email=maryam.zafar@emumba.com, user=undefined
inside user.save...
^[[32minfo^[[39m: Ran cloud function assignTokenToUser for user undefined with:
  Input: {"email":"maryam.zafar@emumba.com"}
  Result: undefined functionName=assignTokenToUser, email=maryam.zafar@emumba.com, user=undefined
[object Object]
```

Now, the log file gives me a user as "undefined", and the call to the function gives me a pending status in the Chrome Network tab in the Inspector tool, until it turns into 502, and then the request is auto generated by the browser again. All other requests get a correct 200 response.

However, the data seems to be saved.. the record against this email address saves the token generated correctly. But the request from the browser fails and the user is "undefined" while in the original log file, I see the correct user Id... everytime it fails, the function automatically runs again (because the browser is generating another request everytime it gets a 502) and since it is actually supposed to send an email, it's running again and again keeps on generating infinate emails...

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understood this finally:

The user will remain undefined until and unlesss I obtain it using the Parse.User.current() method. The data does save into the database because it is a forced update to the record, however until the user is aunthenticated using the current() method, it will remain undefined.

Comment: could you please post your updated code? I am struggling with the same issue

Comment: The updated code is the second chunk of code I have put it - it works fine, i.e it will update the record forcefully even if the user is not logged in and thats why it shows the user to be "undefined" in the log file.

If you want to have a piece of code which updates the logged in user, then you need to use the current() method.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an old post but I spotted clear error in the code:

```
query = new Parse.Query("User")
```

Should be:

```
query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User)
```

Or at least:

```
query = new Parse.Query("_User")
```

As `User` is a predefined class in Parse.